# Intermediate value theorem on semi-open interval

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

IVT states that if $f(x)$ is a continuous function whose domain contains the interval $[a,b]$, then it takes on any given value between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ at some point within the interval.

$[a,b]$ is obviously a closed interval. My question is why IVT is not applicable for semi-open intervals (i.e $(a,b]$ or $[a,b)$)

It is pretty easy to come up with an example where IVT does not hold for an open interval, however, it is more tricky for semi-open, since IVT would apply at least in point $b$ on $(a,b]$ and at least in point $a$ on $[a,b)$.

Is there any example which would prove otherwise?

Comment: What would the supposed formulation even be for a half-open interval, when the function is not even necessarily defined at the open endpoint? I imagine that the function defined by $f(x) = 1/x$ on $(0,1]$ and $f(0)=-1$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Not necessarily undefined. Because if function is undefined, using closed interval would not hold IVT. I would prefer an example where IVT does not hold for semi-open interval but holds for closed one (if such exists). The example you provided would not hold on $[0,1]$ since $f(x)$ is not continuous

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "IVT does not hold for semi-open intervals". What precise statement are you thinking of that you believe is false?

Comment: @Kamran Poladov You say it's pretty easy to come up with a counterexample to IVT on open intervals - but can you find one that doesn't hold on $(a,b)$ but does hold on $[a,b]$? Good luck..